# R: how to shift columns based on conditions

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like the following and, for each row, I want to shift the some columns based on a condition.

```
  flv1 attr1_1 attr2_1 flv2 atrr2_1 atrr2_2 flv3 atrr3_1 atrr3_2
  1    3       4       3    4       2       2    2       5
  2    3       4       3    4       2       1    5       5
  1    3       4       3    4       2       2    4       5
```

and the result I want to achieve is that when the number under flvi is not i. I will move the corresponding values **along the values in the two subsequent columns to the ith column**. Specifically, the result I want to achieve is like the following:

```
flv1 attr1_1 attr2_1 flv2 atrr2_1 atrr2_2 flv3 atrr3_1 atrr3_2
  1    3       4       2    2       5          3    4       2
  1    5       5       2    3       4          3    4       2       
  1    3       4       2    4       5          3    4       2
```

Comment: Please remove all those `**`

Comment: Your column names are inconsistent, both in numbers and spellings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option which is not terribly clean, but, well, neither is your data's form. If the original data.frame is called `df`:

```
library(dplyr)

       # clean out asterisks
df %>% mutate_all(tidyr::extract_numeric) %>% 
    # apply a function to split each row into three groups, order by the flvis, and recombine
    apply(1, function(x){split(x, rep(1:3, each = 3))[order(x[c(1,4,7)])] %>% unlist()}) %>% 
    # clean up matrix back to original data.frame form
    t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(names(df))

##   flv1 attr1_1 attr2_1 flv2 atrr2_1 atrr2_2 flv3 atrr3_1 atrr3_2
## 1    1       3       4    2       2       5    3       4       2
## 2    1       5       5    2       3       4    3       4       2
## 3    1       3       4    2       4       5    3       4       2
```